# Connect two controls in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

I have two boolean elements or swritches.
When I turn on the first one, the second one should switch off and vice versa.
So, I am trying to make elements both indicators and controls.
I read that I have to turn on the Digital Display which is under the visible items submenu but there is no such option.
Could you please help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance.
I am new in LabVIEW, so if this question has already been answered or if it is a stupid question, I am sorry.

Answer (score 3):

If you want one control on the block diagram with two different user indicators, you should use an [XControl](http://labviewwiki.org/XControl), I created a simple example [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3756245/Snippets/DoubleBooleanXCTL.llb).
UPDATE: Added a demo VI to the example /UPDATE
If you want two control on the block diagram with two different user indicators, you should use user event and local variables to control the two states:
[image]

You can only have 'Digital Display' with a gauge or some kind of numeric control

Comment: I use LabVIEW 2012 and I could't open your project. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: I used two toggle switches then I created those two events. Should I put these two controls in a loop?

Comment: @artalexan: The "Event Structure" should be inside a While Loop. Moreover, "Remember to read the terminal of a latched Boolean control in its Value Change event case."

Comment: @artalexan: Also don't forget to handle the "conditional terminal" of the while loop properly.

Comment: Caveats and Recommendations when Using Events in LabVIEW" http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvhowto/caveatsrecmndtnsevnts/

Comment: You should be able to open the llb file. Create a new VI, and drop the XCTL file on the front panel. @Austin Yes it is, but is the most elegant solution in this case. (and not that hard, cost me 10 mins).

Comment: @Ton - 10 minutes plus years spend learning Labview :)  It is an elegant solution though, +1 vote.